# How To Load ads whenever Network is established?

Tags: android, delphi, admob, firemonkey

How can i call the `LoadAd;` procedure whenever The Network is established ?
The reason is this that if user opens the app without connectivity and then connects their Android App to net then app doesn't load at all.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with how ads work, but I would think they should be changing every so often anyway, on some sort of timer.

Comment: if you can tell how to call a procedure on network connection establishment ? then it is going to be easy. i have no idea on that.

Comment: To put it simply, your problem doesn't really have anything to do with ads, it has to do with detecting network state. There's tons of information about that.

Comment: Can't found a working one for me hope you help :)

Comment: What have you tried? How didn't it work?

Comment: All the info i found is in java which i don't know at all

Comment: Android is based on Java. You need to try harder, there are samples both here on SO and elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the network availability based on the method below and call load method in case it

```
public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context _context) {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```